# Php Time and Manual set time value. Count sec

Tags: php, time, count

Twisted my brain around this today and did some search but didnt find any good answers for this.
Take a look here at my example.

```
$time_now = date("H:i:s"); // The current time. (let's say the clock is 14:25:33)
$time_visited = "14:23:33"; // the time page was visited. (set by cookie)
```

So let's say I wanna get the time in sec between $time_visited and $time_now (should be 120sec)
Whats the easiest way to get / count second between these values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[time](http://php.net/time)() returns current timestamp, [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime)() parses given string into a [timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)

```
time() - strtotime("14:23:33")
```